If SubsetSum can be solved in pseudopolynomial time, can we karp reduce SAT/3SAT to it and solve in pseudopolynomial time?
When learning pseudopolynomial time and strong NP-completeness,
this timestamp at this video says:

Which basically
1.SubsetSum can be solved in pseudopolynomial time.
2.SAT, even using unary encoding, has no pseudopolynomial time algorithm, which means it's strong NP-complete.
So my question is:
1.Is 3SAT also strong NP-complete?
2.I know SAT can karp reduce(polynomial time reduce) to 3SAT, and 3SAT can karp reduce
to  SubsetSum, so why can't we karp reduce SAT to SubsetSum, and solve SubsetSum in pseudopolynomial time, hence SAT has a pseudopolynomial time algorithm?
ps: the original video is 8 mins long if you want to check out the context,
but basically it just explains unary number encodings, pseudopolynomial time,
strong NP-completeness.

There's no difference between SAT and 3-SAT here. The crux is that encoding numbers in unary doesn't change the input encoding of SAT or 3-SAT since the inputs aren't numerical, so there's no difference between pseudopolynomial time and polynomial time for these problems, and thus no pseudopolynomial time algorithm (unless P=NP).
The polynomial-time reduction you've presumably seen of 3-SAT to SubsetSum takes an input to 3-SAT and computes an equivalent input of SubsetSum in polynomial time. But when we prove it's polynomial time, we make the assumption that we're encoding the numbers in the resulting SubsetSum input efficiently (say in binary to be explicit, though any base other than unary would work). However, the same SubsetSum input given in unary encoding is exponential in the size of the binary-encoded input, and thus exponential in the size of the 3-SAT input. So the corresponding reduction of 3-SAT to unary-encoded SubsetSum is not polynomial time (even just writing down the equivalent SubsetSum input takes time exponential in the size of the 3-SAT instance).
Also shown in the video snapshot, a more interesting case would be TSP reducing to SubsetSum, since TSP has a numerical component of the input, but is still strongly NP-complete. But again, the polynomial time reduction we know about is between the binary-encoded TSP and the binary-encoded SubsetSum. There is no reason to expect that the same holds for the unary-encoded versions. Just at a naive level, $2^{p(x)}$ is not necessarily polynomial in $2^x,$ but we can understand this specific problem in a little more detail:
When it comes to NP-completeness, the numerical aspect of TSP is subordinate to the graph-theoretical aspect, as evidenced by the NP-completeness of the Hamiltonian Path problem, which is equivalent to a TSP with $O(1)$ distances (so the input size even in unary encoding just scales quadratically with the number of graph vertices). In other words, if we could solve TSP in pseudopolynomial time, we could solve Hamiltonian Path in polynomial time, which is impossible (unless P = NP). So it must be the case that "numerically small" but "graphically big" cases of TSP can reduce to "numerically big" instances of SubsetSum, which would make the reduction between the unary-encoded problems have significantly worse time complexity than the reduction between the binary-encoded problems.
An "in between" (more trivial than TSP, less trivial than 3-SAT) example of a strongly NP-complete problem would be Clique/Independent Set/Vertex Cover, where there is a numerical part of the input, but it's constrained to be numerically on the order of the size of the graph, so whether you encode it in unary or binary has no significant impact on the size of the input.

Is 3SAT also strong NP-complete?

@pokerresources Yes, as I say in the first paragraph, the situation is the same as for SAT.

"In the reduction of 3-SAT to SubsetSum, it's the binary-encoded instance of SubsetSum that can be computed in polynomial time in the size of the 3-SAT instance. "I suspect should be unary encoding? Only unary encoding would be computed in polynomial time?

@pokerresources No, I meant binary. I'm talking about computation of the reduction to subsetSum, not the computation deciding SubsetSum. I'll edit to make that clearer.
